# Make theorem heading link to url

Tags: links

In an answer to another question ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115069/making-a-theorem-into-a-link)), a theorem is nicely linked to another file. When I try to use this to link to a website however (by filling in \url{www. ... .com} instead of ./file.pdf), this gives an error message (Tex capacity exceeded). Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the new theorem style as

```
\newtheoremstyle{linked}
  {}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%      Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  { }%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
     %     \newline = linebreak
  {\href{\thislink}{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}\thmnote{ (#3)}}% Thm head spec
```

Then use `linkthm` as in

```
\begin{linkthm}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
```

MWE (borrowed from that answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheoremstyle{linked}
  {}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%      Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  { }%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
     %     \newline = linebreak
  {\href{\thislink}{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}\thmnote{ (#3)}}% Thm head spec

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] % normal theorems

\theoremstyle{linked}
\newtheorem{innlinkthm}[thm]{Theorem} % theorems with link
\newenvironment{linkthm}[1]
 {\def\thislink{#1}\innlinkthm}
 {\endinnlinkthm}

\begin{document}
\section{Theorems}

\begin{thm}
This is a normal theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{linkthm}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
This has a link.
\end{linkthm}

\begin{linkthm}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}[Attribution]
This has the same link.
\end{linkthm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: As a little extra, this works for both url's and links to files (pdf, flv,...) as I found out testing this solution. Thanks!