# Link a theorem to its restatable

Tags: hyperref, theorems, amsthm, appendix

I have theorems, e.g., a lemma below whose proof is provided in the appendix. How to make the lemma clickable and directed to its restatable (or proof) in the appendix?

Here is the illustration.

[image]

Here is the minimal code for the figure above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, thm-restate}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}[Ni]{lemma}{mylemma}\label{thm:mylemma}
    Given us be the knight, we say Ni. 
\end{restatable}


\appendix 
\section{Appendix: proofs}

\mylemma*
\begin{proof}
It is true, Ni!
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that uses thmtools' internal `\ifthmt@thisistheone` to test if we're in the original or restated theorem. The idea is to define a theorem style, taking inspiration from egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115075/208544), where the heading checks whether or not the theorem is restated, then links appropriately. Use `\NewLinkedTheorem` exactly as you would `\newtheorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,kantlipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{linkedrestate}
  {}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%      Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  { }%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
     %     \newline = linebreak
  {%
    \ifthmt@thisistheone
    \hyperlink{restated:\thisthm}{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\unskip}%
    \thmnote{ (#3)}%
    \hypertarget{orig:\thisthm}{}%
    \else
    \hyperlink{orig:\thisthm}{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\unskip}%
    \thmnote{ (#3)}%
    \hypertarget{restated:\thisthm}{}%
    \fi
    }% Thm head spec

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewLinkedTheorem}{s m o m o}{
    \let\current@thmstyle\thmt@outerstyle % store current theorem style
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \newtheorem*{#2}{#4}
        \theoremstyle{linkedrestate}
        \newtheorem*{linked-#2}{#4}
        \ExpandArgs{e}\theoremstyle{\current@thmstyle} % reset theorem style
        }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#3}{
            \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
                \newtheorem{#2}{#4}
                }{
                \newtheorem{#2}{#4}[#5]
                }
            }{
            \newtheorem{#2}[#3]{#4}
            }
        \theoremstyle{linkedrestate}
        \newtheorem{linked-#2}[#2]{#4}
        \ExpandArgs{e}\theoremstyle{\current@thmstyle} % reset theorem style
        }
    }
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{linkrestatable}{O{} m m +b}{%
    \def\thisthm{#3}%
    \begin{restatable}[#1]{linked-#2}{#3}
    #4
    \end{restatable}
    \AddToHook{cmd/#3/before}{\def\thisthm{#3}}%
    }{}

\NewLinkedTheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\NewLinkedTheorem*{KL}{Klein's Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Theorems}

\begin{linkrestatable}{theorem}{mytag}
\kant[2][1]
\end{linkrestatable}

\begin{theorem}
\kant[3][1]
\end{theorem}

\mytag*

\begin{linkrestatable}{KL}{anothertag}
\kant[4][1]
\end{linkrestatable}

\begin{KL}
\kant[5][1]
\end{KL}

\anothertag*

\end{document}
```

[image: thms]