# Make Theorem header a link to proof environment

Tags: hyperref, theorems, amsthm

I have a similar question to ([Making a theorem into a link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115069/making-a-theorem-into-a-link)) but I was not able to adjust it accordingly.

I have some proofs in an appendix and I would like to have a theorem environment where the header links to the proof. Something like,

```
\begin{linkthm}{\ref{proof:ex_thm}} \label{ex_thm}

\end{linkthm}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code to make it compile so that people don't have to build a small document themselves please? It helps people help you quicker, it only needs to be basic as in starting with your `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Hope someone can answer!

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by `THeorem header into a link` in this context? I would just write `The proof is on page \pageref{proof:ex_thm}` after the theorem. Then it works with and without hyperlinks.

Comment: In the pdf it would say Theorem 4.1 and I would like this to be clickable and lead to the proof. I have a few theorems and I do not want to write after everyone the proof can be found in appendix xx. The link would just make it more conveniently findable.

Comment: And what if the reader prints your document, then now they cannot find it. PDF is not a website the user can do what they want with it, so don't limit them.

Comment: I appreciate your concern for the reader but I would still like to know how it would work :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you make use of the `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` mechanism provided by the `hyperref` package. Both commands take two arguments; the first argument of a linked pair of such commands should be the same.

In the following example, clicking on the word "Pythagoras" in the theorem's header while in the pdf file will take the reader to the associated proof.

[image]

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} % or '\usepackage{ntheorem}'
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % optional
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Main results}

\begin{theorem}[\hyperlink{proof:pyth}{Pythagoras}] \label{thm:pyth}
Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ denote the lengths of the sides 
of a \emph{right triangle}, i.e., of a triangle with 
one angle equal to $90^\circ$. Without loss of generality 
assume that $a\le b<c$. Then $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\clearpage

\appendix

\section{Proofs of all theorems}

\begin{proof}[\hypertarget{proof:pyth}{Proof of \Cref{thm:pyth}}]
\dots
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I was thinking about doing it this way but not all my theorems are named and I also do not want to name them so I am afraid it won't work!

Comment: @bast3456 - Is something stopping you from writing `\hyperlink{proof:pyth}{[Click here to jump to proof]}` *after* `\begin{theorem}`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try and fix the position of the anchor, because `raiselinks` (which should work) doesn't seem to suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} % or '\usepackage{ntheorem}'
\usepackage[raiselinks,colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % optional

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newtheorem{linkthminner}{\hyperlink{\linkthmlabel}{Theorem}}
\crefname{linkthminner}{theorem}{theorems}
\Crefname{linkthminner}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{linkthm}{mo}{%
  % #1 is the label, #2 the possible attribution
  \renewcommand{\linkthmlabel}{#1}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\linkthminner}{\linkthminner[#2]}\label{#1}%
}{\endlinkthminner}
\newcommand{\linkthmlabel}{}% initialize
\newenvironment{linkproof}[1]{%
  \proof[\hypertarget{#1}{\strut\proofname\ of \cref{#1}}.]%
}{\endproof}

\begin{document}

\section{Main results}

\begin{linkthm}{thm:a}
This is a theorem statement. \lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{linkthm}

\begin{linkthm}{thm:b}[Someone]
This is a theorem statement. \lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{linkthm}

\lipsum[1-10]

\appendix

\section{Proofs of all theorems}

\begin{linkproof}{thm:a}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{linkproof}

\begin{linkproof}{thm:b}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{linkproof}

\end{document}
```